# Python – Check if Mac is Playing Music

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to write a simple python script to stop the music being played by a Mac. I found some code that emulates the media buttons from the accepted answer here: [emulate media key press on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045814/emulate-media-key-press-on-mac).

Triggering the play/pause button works perfectly, but I only want to do so if there is music currently playing. Otherwise it turns **on** the music (the opposite of what I'm trying to do. Is there any way to get this information from the system?

I need to check if music was actually playing beforehand so I can know whether to resume it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your use case is macOS specific, you can call AppleScript via Python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e', 'tell application "iTunes" to pause'])
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well. For spotify I had to tweak it to `subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e', 'tell application "Spotify" to pause'])`. However, this doesn't solve my whole problem. I need to check if music was actually playing beforehand so I can know whether to resume it later. (Sorry I wasn't more specific in the original post – edited now.)

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604207/applescript-check-if-computer-is-playing-any-sound) might help. You can use `pmset -g` to see if `coreaudiod` is running.

Comment: Unfortunately that gives the same response whether Spotify is playing or paused.

Comment: Looks like Spotify has AppleScript bindings you can use to check the player status. You might be able to modify the code from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435412/spotifys-player-state-is-available-in-the-editor-but-in-a-packaged-app-it-g) to get what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Actually ended up just coding the whole thing in AppleScript.